# Where is a good place to save app configurations on Linux

Tags: linux, user-interface

I am writing an application, which needs to save some settings to be persistent between runs (last opened file, user preferences, etc...). Where is a good place to save it on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how you define good, but how about:

```
${HOME}/.your-app-name
```

Checking my own home folder, that seems what the likes of Atom, Gimp, Mozilla, SSH, Vim, etc. are doing.

Answer (score 3):

According to the latest convention and [XDG standards](https://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) you should use

```
${HOME}/.config/your-app-name
```

which ought to be defined in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable

If you plan to distribute your application with [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) then you will be provided with path inside `${HOME}/snap` with [`SNAP_USER_DATA` environment](https://docs.snapcraft.io/reference/env) value.